# Bootstrap Popover functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap popovers and they should be able to open the sidepanel.

Also please find the related code in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/eLLaacju/

I wanted to achieve the below issue:
The popover should open on data-trigger="hover" and stay as it has content in which if we can click the Text (Click Me) it should open a sidepanel. data-trigger='focus' doesn't help either.

Could you please help me, below is the related code to it.

HTML

```
<i id="popover-a" class="circle-macro" tabindex="0" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">i</i>

<div id="popover-content-a" class="hidden">
 <div>
  <h6><b>Heading</b></h6>
   <p>Content <a href="#">Click Me</a></p>
 </div>
</div>


<i id="popover-b" class="circle-macro" tabindex="1" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">i</i>

<div id="popover-content-b" class="hidden">
 <div>
  <h6><b>Heading</b></h6>
   <p>Content <a href="#">Click Me</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#popover-a").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-a').html();     
    }
  });
  $("#popover-b").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-b').html();     
    }
  });
})
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: can you put in jsfiddle? show the current result

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/eLLaacju/

Comment: @DonaldWu could you please check it once. In the fiddle the popover opens when hovered, but I want it to stay and want to click the 'Click Me' which will open the sidepanel and also it should close whenever the 'Click Me' is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code helps me:

```
$(function () {
  $("#popover-a").popover({
    html: true, trigger: 'click hover', delay: {show: 50, hide: 4000},
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-a').html();     
    }
  });
  $("#popover-b").popover({
    html: true, trigger: 'click hover', delay: {show: 50, hide: 4000},
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-b').html();     
    }
  });
})
```